# Delay in ListViewItemComparer sorting when clicking on the column

Tags: c#

I made a `ListViewItemComparer()` method and it works for ascending and descending. However, sometimes I have to click twice for the `ListView` to update.

Any reason why this happens?

```
private bool isAscending = true;
public class ListViewItemComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    private int column;
    private bool isAscending;

    public ListViewItemComparer(int column, bool isAscending)
    {
        this.column = column;
        this.isAscending = isAscending;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        ListViewItem item1 = (ListViewItem)x;
        ListViewItem item2 = (ListViewItem)y;

        // Compare the values of the clicked column
        int result = String.Compare(item1.SubItems[column].Text, item2.SubItems[column].Text);

        // Reverse the result if descending order
        if (!isAscending)
        {
            result *= -1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

private void OfficerListVIew_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the clicked column
    ColumnHeader clickedColumn = officerListView.Columns[e.Column];

    // Sort the ListView by the clicked column
    officerListView.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column, isAscending);

    // Toggle the sorting order
    isAscending = !isAscending;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to check in a debugger what's happening when you click? Does it hit a breakpoint inside of `OfficerListVIew_ColumnClick`? BTW I'd advise not to create new ListViewItemComparer object every time you click a column. Just make `isAscending` and `column` as properties of the class and update them.